# Error when submitting variables through Mailgun with Python

Tags: python, mailgun

I'm trying to send mail through Mailgun with Python, in that instance I'm trying to push a variable alongside.

My code is the following:

```
requests.post("MailGun URL",
              auth=("api", "api-key"),
              data={
                  "from":"From_Mail",
                  "to":["To_Mail"],
                  "template":"template_name",
                  "subject":"Testing some things",
                  "h:X-Mailgun-Variables": {"firstname": "John"}
              })
```

If I use the above without "X-Mailgun-Variables" I'm not experiencing any problems, but with the above I get the following error message:

```
"delivery-status": {
        "code": 621,
        "message": "",
        "attempt-no": 1,
        "description": "Failed to decode variables",
        "session-seconds": 0
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the solution myself - for future reference:

```
"h:X-Mailgun-Variables": {"firstname": "John"}
```

The above ss only for SMTP use.

For API use:

```
"v:firstname":"John"
```

Answer (score 3):

Should work if you transform to JSON i.e.

```
import json
...

"h:X-Mailgun-Variables": json.dumps({"firstname": "John"})
```

Answer (score 3):

When using their Node SDK `mailgun-js`, you need to use `JSON.stringify()` to format the payload correctly.

For example.

```js
const data = {
  from: 'John Smith <john@smith.com>',
  to: 'recipient@example.com',
  subject: 'Subject line',
  template: 'template-name',
  'h:X-Mailgun-Variables': JSON.stringify({
    name: `Morgan`,
    occupation: `Software Developer`
  })
};

await mailgun.messages().send(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tired your way but it did not work.
Expected value is a string of the key and value pair

```
test1 = '{"firstname": "'
test2 = str(data['first_name'])
test3 = '"}'
test4 = test1+test2+test3

"h:X-Mailgun-Variables": test4
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by identifying why the code provided addresses the problem presented by the asker and why it is an alternative approach.